# RS-232 framing error

Tags: serial-port

New here, so a bit about myself first:

I am a fire alarm commissioning engineer by trade, but like to mess with electronics as a hobby. 
my main area of interest is integration between various systems (which is one of the reasons I like doing fire alarms, as they interface with most systems in big buildings) and have recently started getting more involved with serial comms to interface systems, rather than boring relay contacts.

In my house, I have an 8X8 audio/video matrix switcher, this connects the stereo systems in all the rooms to each other so that i can patch any rooms audio to any of the other rooms in the house.
This switcher has an RS-232 serial port on the back, which I'm hoping I can interface to either a PI or an arduino, so that I can control it via a web interface.

After a while searching, I found the protocol for it online... but things haven't gone so smoothly after that unfortunately.

Currently I'm just using a usb-232 converter and a null modem cable, along with a program called 232 analyser on my laptop...
I  can read data fine, and send data to the unit... but it keeps spitting back a 'framing error' message.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, please could someone advise? this is the first time I've really used serial so pointers would be cool.
One thing i did think is that the protocol specifies:

- RS-232C STANDARD
- START Bit 1
- STOP Bit 1
- DATA Bit 8
- PARITY Bit EVEN
- BAUD RATE 9600bps
- CODE ASCII
- TERMINATE

but my analyser program only lets me set the baud rate, data bits, parity, stop bit, and data format. not start bit. could that be my issue? and if so how do i get around it?
thanks so much in advance!

[image: protocol page 1]

[image: protocol page 2]

Comment: No, there is only ever 1 start bit so it is not something you ever configure.  You ought to assume that the document is incorrect and tinker with Stopbits, Parity and Baudrate.

Comment: Are you talking about the EO error message in the picture?  A link to the documentation would help.

Comment: Eight data bits **with** (even) parity (for ASCII) is a somewhat unusual configuration.  If you're not sending 11 bits per frame, which could be confirmed with a 'scope, then that would cause a framing error.  Also, make sure that this *"framing error"* is referring to RS-232 data chars, and not a message frame.

Comment: I agree that 8 data bits paired with even parity is very odd. I would also suggest using a different serial analyzer link RealTerm or Termite. I use a licensed version of 232Analyzer at work and love it but the free version is just too restrictive for really doing to the kind of work you seem to be pursuing.

Answer (score 1):

The format most commonly used for serial connections use one start bit, 8 data bits, no parity, and one stop bit.